# set -e and set -x in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, command

What is the difference between

```
set -e
set -x
```

and

```
set -xe
```

I'm  getting different responses for these. Please help me getting it clarified.

Comment: Please edit your question to include actual test case or at least the exact messages you are getting for each set as you list them above. Good luck.

Answer (score 54):

```
set -x
```

Print shell command before execute it. This feature help programmers to track their shell script.

```
set -e
```

If the return code of one command is not 0 and the caller does not check it, the shell script will exit. This feature make shell script robust.

`set -e` and `set -x` often appear at the head of shell script:

```
set -x
set -e

echo "I am a shell script."
```

Or use as shell command:

```
sh -xe shell_script.sh
```

Reference: http://julio.meroh.net/2010/01/set-e-and-set-x.html

Answer (score 6):

Presumably you are talking about bash.  According to its [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html), `-e` (see section [4.3.1](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin)) tells bash to exit under certain conditions (which may apply to your script).  If that is the case, "`set -xe`" might print more of the trace before exiting than "`set -e`" followed by "`set -x`".

Comment: Actually i getting a failure & it is exiting immediately in case of -xe and not executing the lines of code below it. But in other case the same failure occurs but the lines of code below it executes! This is my confusion!

Comment: With a (short) script which demonstrates the problem, we might be able to offer some explanation.  The bash documentation provides some outlines of its behavior with "-e", but for instance if the script is in some compound statement, bash could wait for doing the trace until it had done substitution and collected return statuses.

Comment: @ThomasDickey (i) I'm calling this script without any of those 3 arguments; how do I determine what nixOS supplies them by default? (ii) What do you mean by the "keep" argument? Do you mean `--keep-going`?